# JSON: can't access nested data (only through indexes)

Tags: javascript, json

For some reason I have trouble accessing JSON with my JavaScript code. These are the problems I keep having:

1) I can only access data inside of 'details' by using index ( $scope.details[0] ), but not ( $scope.details.difficulty ). Why?

2) I can't access data of ingredients using

$scope.ingredients[1] = rdata['0'] why is that?

3) How do I access ingredients and individual amounts and names?

**Here's my code:**

JSON:

```
        {"title": "Salmon with beetroot, feta & lime salsa",
                "details": {
                  "difficulty": "easy",
                  "prep_time": "5 mins",
                  "cook_time": "10 mins"
                },
                "ingredients": {
                  "count":"3",
                  "0":{
                    "amount":"500 g",
                    "name": "salmon"
                  },
                  "1":{
                    "amount":"200 g",
                    "name": "beetroot"
                  },
                  "2":{
                    "amount":"150g",
                    "name":"feta"
                  }
                },
                "method":{
                  "step_count":"2",
                  "steps":{
                    "0": "To this and that",
                    "1": "Once this and that is done do that this"
                  }
                }
              };
```

JavaScript:

```
$http.get('/api/recipe')
  .success(function(data) {

    $scope.title = data['title'];
    $scope.details = data['details'];
    $scope.details[0] = data['difficulty'];
    $scope.details[1] = data['prep_time'];
    $scope.details[2] = data['cook_time'];
    $scope.ingredients = data['ingredients'];
    $scope.ingredients[0] = data['count'];
    //$scope.ingredients[1] = rdata['0'];
    $scope.ingredients[1].amount = data['amount'];
    /*$scope.ingredients[2] = rdata['1'];
    $scope.ingredients[3] = rdata['2'];*/
    $scope.method = data['method'];
    $scope.method[0] = data['step_count'];
    $scope.method[1] = data['steps'];
    $scope.recipeData = data;

    console.log(data['title']);
  })

  .error(function(data) {
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
  });
```

HTML:

```
<h4>Details</h4>
<p>Dificulty: {{details.difficulty}}</p>
<p>Preparation time: {{details.prep_time}}</p>
<p>Cooking time: {{details.cook_time}}</p>
</br>

<h4>Ingredients</h4>
<p>Number of total ingredients: {{ingredients.count}}</p>
<!--<p>{{ingredients.0}}</p>

<p>2) {{ingredients.count}}</p>
<p>3) {{ingredients.count}}</p>
-->
<p>1) {{ingredients[1].amount}}</p>
</br>

<h4>Method</h4>
<p>{{method}}</p>
<p>Total steps required: {{method.step_count}}</p>
<p>Steps: {{method.steps}}</p>
```

Any ideas?

**THANKS!**

Comment: Why are you doing all this shunting around of properties? Why not just `$scope.recipe = data` and `<p>Difficulty: {{recipe.details.difficulty}}</p>`?

Comment: @slim this works! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can only access data inside of 'details' by using index (
>   $scope.details[0] ), but not ( $scope.details.difficulty ). Why?

Because `details` is a key of an object `$scope.details[0]` expects details to be an array. Object keys cannot be accessed by index , but by `dot(.)` or `square []` braces

> I can't access data of ingredients using $scope.ingredients[1] =
>   rdata['0'] why is that?

Same reason as above. ingredients just another key to the same object

> How do I access ingredients and individual amounts and names?

```js
var x = {
  "title": "Salmon with beetroot, feta & lime salsa",
  "details": {
    "difficulty": "easy",
    "prep_time": "5 mins",
    "cook_time": "10 mins"
  },
  "ingredients": {
    "count": "3",
    "0": {
      "amount": "500 g",
      "name": "salmon"
    },
    "1": {
      "amount": "200 g",
      "name": "beetroot"
    },
    "2": {
      "amount": "150g",
      "name": "feta"
    }
  },
  "method": {
    "step_count": "2",
    "steps": {
      "0": "To this and that",
      "1": "Once this and that is done do that this"
    }
  }
};
var getIndigrents = x.ingredients // will give an object
// Here [] is a way of acceesing object key but this does not mean to be index
console.log(getIndigrents["0"].amount)
console.log(getIndigrents["0"].name)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are overwriting the same variable:
with

```
$scope.ingredients = data['ingredients'];
```

you initialize it with the content of ingredients
and with

```
$scope.ingredients[0] = data['count'];
$scope.ingredients[1].amount = data['amount'];
```

you transform the variable in an array of undefined as you have to do `data['ingredients']['count']` to access the nested fields